# How do I share a reverse SSH tunnel on a network?

Tags: ssh, reverse-tunnel

I have a remote computer on a 3G PPP connection.
I can't connect to this computer via the Internet as I believe the PPP IP pool uses NAT to connect to the Internet (I get given a 10.x.x.x address when I connect)

So I get the remote computer to create a SSH connection to a server on the Internet.
I can then tunnel down this connection from the server and get a shell on the remote computer. Great.

I want to be able to access the Web interface of a camera on the remote network.
So I create a second SSH tunnel that redirects traffic to the address of the camera, ie:
ssh -R 9000::

From my Internet host this works, I get the web page:
wget 127.0.0.1:9000
Great

Now I need this to work from my client PC so:

Client PC --> Internet server --tunnel--> Remote computer --> IP camera

So essentially I need to make my reverse SSH tunnel available over the network.

I assumed if I just used iptables to forward incoming traffic on a certain port on my Internet server to 127.0.0.1:9000 that would work but I haven't been able to make it work after hours of playing with iptables, NAT etc.

Should this work?

Comment: did youu ensure you are listening on all interfaces on port 9000?

Comment: Perhaps easier to avoid terms like local and remote particularly when it is unclear. The 3G computer is the one you are calling "remote", it is behind NAT or a NAT like thing.  You SSH from there to another computer which runs an SSH server, for the Internet. That's ssh -D and opens a port on the 3G computer to access the internet.  A device on the 3G side has a camera or is a camera, So you use ssh -R for that one from the 3G. OK I think I got that

Comment: Is that above comment of mine correct?  I am not sure off hand what the default is, but when you do the ssh -R command, often people do PORT:IP:PORT but you can do IP:PORT:IP:PORT  where the first IP is *  as opposed to 127.0.0.1  So, complicate that PORT:IP:PORT part after the -R, to be IP:PORT:IP:PORT and make that first IP * and it should allow others to connect, I suppose, see if that works. I think it's * rather than 0.0.0.0 but report back. Though from what i've read, I think * should be default.

Comment: It looks like in my case at least, it's defaulting to 127.0.0.1  So using * or 0.0.0.0 might do it. But try it and see. Also, You ask if it can be shared. But, can 2+ computers connect to your camera at your remote side e.g. even not using ssh, is it possible to do it?

Comment: hi. I agree, using local and remote is unclear. Yes the "3G" computer is behind a NAT pool when it connects (gets a 10. address). This is the problem. If it was getting a real internet address I could connect directly to it directly from outside. Because I can't I creating the SSH connection and then tunnelling back down it. As I mentioned this works fine from the "Internet" computer and I can connect to the webcam fine. The final hurdle is to allow another computer to use this tunnel, not just the "Internet" computer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/767524/why-can-i-not-connect-to-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel-port-remotely-even-with-gatewaypo

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `-o GatewayPorts=yes` to allow other hosts than local to use your tunnel.
From the man-page:

> Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local 
>   forwarded ports.  By default, ssh(1) binds local port forwardings
>   to the loopback address.  This prevents other remote hosts from
>   connecting to forwarded ports.  GatewayPorts can be used to specify that ssh should bind
>   local port forwardings to the wildcard address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to 
>   forwarded ports.  The argument must be “yes” or “no”.  The default is “no”.

Comment: GatewaysPorts=yes must be set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, not passed to the ssh client.  See:  https://superuser.com/questions/767524/why-can-i-not-connect-to-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel-port-remotely-even-with-gatewaypo