# Why can I not connect to a reverse SSH tunnel port remotely, even with GatewayPorts enabled?

Tags: ssh, port, tunnel

I require constant SSH access to a host in our department, whose IP address is dynamically allocated. I've set up a remote SSH tunnel from the target host to one of our hosts that does posess a static ip address:

```
ssh -f -N -g -R :22223:localhost:22 tunnelhost
```

When I point SSH at local port `22223` on the tunnel host, the tunnel works fine. My problem is that I cannot seem to get the tunnel bound to anything other than localhost, though - i.e. when I try to SSH remotely to `tunnelhost:12323`, there is no open port to receive it. I've also tried:

```
ssh -f -N -R :22223:localhost:22 tunnelhost -o GatewayPorts=yes
```

But still no luck. Netstat shows me:

```
[me@tunnel_host ~]$ netstat -an | grep 22223
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:22223         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:22223               :::*                    LISTEN
```

Confirming that the tunnel is only bound to localhost. I've added a port exception on the tunnel host, with firewalld-cmd, and ensured no network hardware is interfering with the connection. Any ideas as to what it could be?

Cheers, James.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to enable `GatewayPorts=yes` in the config for SSHd (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), not the client in order to enable binding to interfaces other than loopback on remote ports.

```
-o GatewayPorts=yes
```

Only works for local ports when passed to the `ssh` command.

Comment: Darth Android, Thank you for your reply. It seems you are correct about -g and -o GatewayPorts only working for (-L)ocal tunnels. For the sake of completeness, here's a little more information about this issue, in case anyone else runs into it in future. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=228064

Comment: `GatewayPorts=clientspecified` is a somewhat more secure setting, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/50064/reverse-port-tunnelling. In this case, the empty bind address (trailing colon in `:22223:localhost:2`) is required.

Comment: I'd argue that the `GatewayPorts=clientspecified` setting itself isn't more secure, but rather it allows for more control over which connections will be bound to wildcard, versus just having them all bound to wildcard.

Comment: Also, restart sshd after modding the sshd_config (in case you forget)

Comment: ⚠️ Be aware that `GatewayPorts=yes` will open the forwarded ports to the world.