# Open port for reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, putty, tunnel

I have opened a reverse SSH tunnel from machine A (Windows) sitting behind a NAT to machine B (Ubuntu) on port 4000. I can access my service running on machine A from machine B at the address localhost:4000. However, I cannot access this same service from machine C on the same subnet as machine B (i.e. at machine_b_ip:4000). I can reach machine B from machine C on other ports without issue (such as 22 or 80), but it seems like machine B does not want to listen on port 4000.

I have checked and saved both "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" and "Remote ports do the same" in the PuTTY settings on machine A.

[image: PuTTY]

There seems to be no firewall active:

```
machine_B:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Telenet fails to connect on port 4000

```
machine_C>telnet machine_b_ip 4000
Connecting To machine_b_ip...Could not open connection to the host, on port 4000: Connect failed
```

Comment: Enable on Ubuntu in `sshd_config` directive: `GatewayPorts on` and restart `ssh` daemon

Comment: Thanks, this did it. There are many guides out there that cover reverse SSH tunnel, uncluding on SuperUser, and a suprising number do not mention this at all. I guess my question is a [duplicate of this](https://superuser.com/questions/767524/why-can-i-not-connect-to-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel-port-remotely-even-with-gatewaypo). Otherwise, it is resolved.